# Masstransit RPC (RabbitMq) throughput limit

Tags: rabbitmq, masstransit, throughput

We are using Masstransit with RabbitMq for making RPCs from one component of our system to others.

Recently we faced the limit of throughput on client side, measured about 80 completed responses per second.

While trying to investigate where the problem was, I found that requests were processed fast by the RPC server, then responses were put to callback queue, and then, the queue processing speed was 80 M\s

This limit is only on client side. Starting another process of the same client app on the same machine doubles requests throughput on the server side, but then I see two callback queues, filled with messages, are being consumed each with the same 80 M\s

We are using single instance of IBus

```
builder.Register(c =>
{
    var busSettings = c.Resolve<RabbitSettings>();
    var busControl = MassTransitBus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
        {
            var host = cfg.Host(new Uri(busSettings.Host), h =>
            {
                h.Username(busSettings.Username);
                h.Password(busSettings.Password);
            });

            cfg.UseSerilog();

            cfg.Send<IProcessorContext>(x =>
            {
               x.UseCorrelationId(context => context.Scope.CommandContext.CommandId);
            });

    }
);

return busControl;
})
.As<IBusControl>()
.As<IBus>()
.SingleInstance();
```

The send logic looks like this:

```
var busResponse = await _bus.Request<TRequest, TResult>(
                destinationAddress: _settings.Host.GetServiceUrl<TCommand>(queueType),
                message: commandContext,
                cancellationToken: default(CancellationToken),
                timeout: TimeSpan.FromSeconds(_settings.Timeout),
                callback: p => { p.WithPriority(priority); });
```

Has anyone faced the problem of that kind?
My guess that there is some program limit in the response dispatch logic. It might be the Max thread pool size, or the size of the buffer, also the prefetch count of response queue.
I tried to play with .Net thread pool size, but nothing helped.

I'm kind of new to Masstransit and will appreciate any help with my problem.
Hope it can be fixed in configuration way

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are a few things you can try to optimize the performance. I'd also suggest checking out the MassTransit-Benchmark and running it in your environment - this will give you an idea of the possible throughput of your broker. It allows you to adjust settings like prefetch count, concurrency, etc. to see how they affect your results.

Also, I would suggest using one of the request clients to reduce the setup for each request/response. For example, create the request client once, and then use that same client for each request.

`var serviceUrl = yourMethodToGetIt<TRequest>(...);
var client = Bus.CreateRequestClient<TRequest>(serviceUrl);`

Then, use that `IRequestClient<TRequest>` instance whenever you need to perform a request.

`Response<Value> response = await client.GetResponse<TResponse>(new Request());`

Since you are just using RPC, I'd highly recommend settings the receive endpoint queue to non-durable, to avoid writing RPC requests to disk. And adjust the bus prefetch count to a higher value (higher than the maximum number of concurrent requests you may have by 2x) to ensure that responses are always delivered directly to your awaiting response consumer (it's an internal thing to how RabbitMQ delivers messages).

`var busControl = Bus.Factory.CreateUsingRabbitMq(cfg =>
{
   cfg.PrefetchCount = 1000;
}`

Comment: Link to benchmark: https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit-Benchmark